# Tune-in to next radio station on FM radio without unlocking the phone

Tags: fm-radio

I'm using Moto E 1st gen. on Android KitKat. I'm used to listening to FM radio while travelling, but whenever I want to tune-in to other radio station, I have to unlock the phone first because I'm using a pattern lock. I'm also using headset, but there's no control buttons, so I can't change the radio station with it.

Since it's difficult to unlock while travelling (moving) and sometimes takes too many attempts, is it possible to tune-in to next radio station without unlocking? Perhaps a widget on the lock-screen?

Comment: What device model, Android version and radio app are you using? (currently assuming Android KitKat or older, since there's no lock screen widget on Lollipop or later)

Comment: android kitkat , moto E (gen 1)

Comment: The Lollipop version of [Motorola FM radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.fmplayer) app has the lock screen notification from where you can switch stations. But that's not available for Kitkat yet so this isn't officially possible. You can try to update your FM radio app in the playstore and see if there's an option.

Comment: This is why I don't use a lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tired to double press the button in your headset? The stock radio player app should do it. And in case if does not there are plenty of apps ([Headset Control Center](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shengande.degausslabs) to name one) in market that can recognise the double press and do a task for you, which could be change the radio station.

**Update:**
After realizing the absence of headset button through the OP's comment, I suggest to use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) and [Intent Radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.smblott.intentradioio&hl=en) app.  The concept is that the Tasker can be used to identify a trigger. This could be head set plug in, head set removed, power button pressed, volume buttom pressed, movement gesture - few listed out of many options.  This trigger will raise an intent to the Intent Radio which can change the radio station.

Comment: thanks for the sugession , but the issue is i don't have button control in headset, that's why specifically asked lock screen widgit

Comment: I was only trying to help. Had if you mentioned it explicitly I might not have suggested this answer. And will the negative voter care to leave a comment why voted down unless it is the OP.